# iPad Safari Development toolbar

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Is there some kind of developer toolbar that can be used within the iPad/Safari?

I am aware of the same on desktop Safari as well as I know there is a Debugger option in iPad/Safari but is there a quick way of editing CSS/JS within the iPad/Safari?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no developer toolbar for Safari iPad, but you could definitely use something like [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to do most of what you want!  Just add the bookmarklet to your bookmarks, and then load it while you're looking at your page.

Your other option is [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/), a remote debugger and part of the PhoneGap project. Essentially, it lets you run an interface similar to the Chrome document inspector on your desktop machine, that manipulates the document on your iPad or iPhone. The commenter below brought my attention to this awesome tool a year ago, but since then the project's URL has changed so I'm adding it here.

FirebugLite does have some issues with rendering speed and dealing with JavaScript, and it additionally doesn't scale its fonts very well. For these reasons, Weinre is definitely a more powerful tool - but also harder to start using.

Comment: Oh damn, Weinre looks hot. +1.

Comment: @sudowned is there a version requirement here? I just updated my ipad and MacBook to the latest versions, yet the option to connect to the iPad does not appear under the develop menu.

Comment: Uncertain - you might want to talk to honk31, author of the answer below which actually involves the connection method.

Comment: Firebug Lite is now completely dead, sadly.

Answer (score 55):

On the ipad go to *Settings > Safari > Advanced* and activate the Web Inspector.

Connect your ipad with your computer.

On your computer open *Safari*, enable the developer tools in the settings.
check the above menu for the tab *Developer* and find your *iPad* there.

Full control via console from your desktop machine over the *iOS Safari* and you're done!

PS: This works exact the same way with the *iPhone* as well..

Comment: Tried this and it works like a charm! One thing I stumbled upon is that private browsing has to be disabled in Safari though.

Comment: acutally i dont think this works on windows, since apple stopped developing safari for windows (not 100% sure). i tried it on my virtual machine but couldnt find that entry in the development menue.

Comment: I can confirm you this feature is available only for Mac's Safari 6. Safari for Windows was stopped at the version 5 so it's not available.

Comment: By "computer" he means Mac. This does not work in Windows, unless you use Node.js. More here: https://medium.com/@brandonmitchell_80736/debugging-web-applications-on-ios-with-windows-10-9b12fcda171a

Answer (score 6):

You can use this little trick to enable Firebug Lite or any other debugging tool built into a bookmarklet, works quite well actually!

http://www.blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/

Comment: Thanks! This was useful(and necessary, I was like..okay how do I save the frigging bookmark!)

Comment: The link appears to have succumbed to rot.

Comment: It can still be found on Wayback Machine https://web.archive.org/web/20111114032339/http://www.blog.cordslatton.com/2010/11/debugging-ios-mobile-safari-ipad-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for i[Pad]Os Safari [Web Inspector on App Store](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1584825745), should work with the iPadOS 15+.

This is how it's described on the [author's site](https://andadinosaur.com/launch-web-inspector-for-ios):

> Web Inspector is a Safari extension on iOS and iPadOS that works like its desktop counterpart but is less powerful. It allows web developers to edit web pages on the fly, debug JavaScript, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a Mac computer, with the same Safari version as the one in the iPad/iPhone, you're out of luck - as many here have already said.

However, there is a way using Node.js, which I am stealing from [here](https://medium.com/@brandonmitchell_80736/debugging-web-applications-on-ios-with-windows-10-9b12fcda171a), for this "answer".

The article refers to Windows 10, but I've tested this with Windows 11 and it works like a charm.

I won't repeat the steps in the website here, but trust me it works.

Answer (score -1):

Safari iPad doesn't have a development tool, but it does have a debug toolbar.  It's features include:

1. Viewing messages sent to the console
2. Viewing JavaScript errors
3. Viewing CSS errors

So it's not great for development, but it's a lot better than nothing.  Here's how to enable it:

1. Open settings
2. Safari
3. Advanced
4. Enable debug console

You should then see a banner at the top of web pages with messages from the debug console.

Comment: Has this been removed on iOS 6.1?  I know it was there on 6.0 but since upgrading to 6.1 I can't find it.  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score -3):

There is a set of developer tools in Safari.
Go to Settings > Advanced and take a good look :)

Comment: This question is about Safari on the iPad, not desktop Safari.