# Using javascript to change class of a div to show or hide it causes the layout to break on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad

I'm new to the HTML\CSS\Javascript thing, so please excuse my incompetence. I know for some bits (mainly class modification) I'm not using jQuery, but only because I couldn't get it to work, so I went old-skool.

I have a web page (here: http://dashboards.kantarhealthspain.com/uk/segmentation/Segmentation_v0.4.html) that works just fine in Chrome (and Safari) on my desktop. You click on the massive squares in the middle of the page, and then click on the >> to go to the next 'page'. Eventually you get to the point where it hides\unhides one of 4 segments based on what you've chosen. It's a bit clunky, but it works, which right now is a win...

When I view the same page on an iPad, the layout isn't quite as good, but that's not my problem. When you get to the final question to show\hide the segments, it seems to change the way the whole page is rendered - every element seems to take up so much room.

Debugging on an iPad is very difficult, as I'm using a Windows machine to develop, and the Safari emulator doesn't actually emulate what's going on, as it doesn't break on desktop Safari (for Windows).

I don't even know where to start looking on this - any hints would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Now I've fixed the evil HTML, it looks like when the divs at the bottom are shown\hidden, the height of each div above doubles(?) I've made the background of NavDiv and Breaker fuschia and maroon so they show up, and the double in size. The height is a percentage of the size of the page (I presume) - what's going on there?! Does the percentage recalculate when areas are unhidden?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: woah, that text ruins my eyes

Comment: I guess that using a valid markup could be a good starting point. Your page is (or at least seems) broken, according to w3c validator there are 115 errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://dashboards.kantarhealthspain.com/uk/segmentation/Segmentation_v0.4.html

Comment: Yeah, not sure what's happened with the text; frankly I'll come back and fix that once the functionality is fixed...

Comment: @PaoloStefan - I guess this is a good place to start - getting this stuff fixed I guess will as least minimise other potential problems.

Comment: @PaoloStefan It was the foreignObjects that were causing the validator to break, and once removed, it passes as an HTML5 doc. It does, however, still do the same thing when you touch on the final next button. The most frustrating thing about this is I don't know where to go next with the debugging!

Comment: Sorry to post again as comment, but I'm not sure it solves the problem: your .Showing CSS class adds not only display:block but also margin. This could cause an overflow in the container element which could result in a different height. BTW see this question, firebug lite is available for ipad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734323/ipad-safari-development-toolbar

Comment: It's unfortunately not that (I don't think...). I've tried looking at the document height (by adding in alert()s), and depending on the selections chosen, the document height is different after selecting the final question (Calcium Channel Blockers), and when it's shown\hidden the segments. At least this gives me something to focus on.

Comment: So I guess now I need to find out how I set the height of the page - or at least the viewport?

Comment: mhm... I think you can use media queries to set a different style for Ipad. I don't know how big is your CSS, but maybe you can identify your problem starting from scratch on Ipad media.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help - It seemed to boil down to having all my heights as percentages of their parent, but the body not having a fixed height. When I hardcoded it to the height of the iPad, it all seemed to work nicely. I need to revisit this, but as a v0.1, it'll do to demo.