# Heroku app not loading on iPhone - Node / React

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I've built a Node/React/Webpack app and just deployed it. Everything works just like on localhost for my desktop (Ubuntu 16.04 with Chrome and Firefox) and from an Android Galaxy Core phone using Chrome, but on an iPhone 5S using Safari and Firefox I don't get anything except the name of the app showing up in the title of the tab.

I don't think it's a case of CSS messing with me - I tried to go directly to one of the internal pages and it didn't redirect me to the main page like it should have, so I think it isn't loading at all.

Are there any common gotchas with this? This is the second Node/React/Webpack app I've built, using pretty similar methods, and the first one did fine on everything.

Here is my `package.json` file - if there's anything else that would be helpful to see just ask.

```
{
  "name": "last-minute",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "connect to others nearby for last-minute hanging out",
  "main": "webpack.prod.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.5.0",
    "npm": "6.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config jest.config.json",
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.js --mode development && node server/server.js",
    "light": "webpack --config webpack.light.js --mode development && node light-server/style-server.js"
  },
  "author": "Doug Sauve",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.44",
    "@google/maps": "^0.4.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.14",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.5",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-geocode": "0.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "validator": "^10.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.join(__dirname, `/src/main.js`)],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, `/public`),
    filename: `bundle.js`
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules'),
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
            plugins: [
              ['transform-class-properties', { 'spec': true }],
              ['transform-object-rest-spread']
            ]
          }
        }
      }, {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const merge = require ('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require ('webpack');

const common = require ('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
});
```

It seems to be an issue on older versions of iOS, not sure what the breakpoint is.

Comment: Can you explain how you build you application before you pass it off to Heroku?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean by 'build', but I built the app completely on localhost before deploying it - I started a Node backend using MongoDB/Mongoose, got Webpack and React working and then began building the app, styling only the bare minimum until functionality was pretty much complete. Before I sent the app to Heroku, I got everything happy on the dev server, then built and ran it in production mode. Does that tell you what you needed to know?

Comment: update - the issue is not on all iOS. It doesn't work on iPhone 5, but it does on iPhone 6. Not sure which versions of iOS are running on either device. My sister is going to try running it on her Mac this evening and see if any error messages pop up.

Comment: The reason that I ask about the build process is because it sounds like you might not be transpiling your ES6 Javascript to a version that most browsers can understand. What sort of errors are you getting in the console of browsers that this is not working on?

Comment: I don't see any error at all, but I also haven't gotten the chance to look at a Mac console and see why. Hopefully soon. I'll post my webpack config file and update this as soon as I can get access to a Mac for error messages.

Comment: If it's not running on a specific iPhone how will looking at the Mac console help?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there's a way to get to developer tools and a console on iPhones. But maybe there is an error being thrown by the app that I simply can't access on my phone, but would be able to on a Mac.

Comment: Yes, you can access an iOS device’s Safari console. See this answer for instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15298016

Comment: @DougSauve any update here? i have the same error, runs everywhere but chrome ios in iphone5S